# Inserting data into SQlite databases in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm currently building a login app using SQlite as the database. I've created the database however I am unable to insert data. I have tried using multiple online tutorials and suggestions and can't seem to crack it. I always receive the not successfully created toast message rather than the correctly installed toast message. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Database creation code:

```
   public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE USER (USERNAME TEXT PRIMARY KEY, PASSWORD TEXT, FIRSTNAME TEXT, SECONDNAME TEXT, FINGERPRINT BLOB, FACE BLOB)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS USER");
}
// Inserting into database

public boolean insertUserData (String inputUsername, String inputPassword, String inputFirstName, String inputSecondName)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("inputUsername", inputUsername);
    contentValues.put("inputPassword", inputPassword);
    contentValues.put("inputFirstName", inputFirstName);
    contentValues.put("inputSecondName", inputSecondName);
    long result = db.insert("User",null, contentValues);
    if (result ==-1)
    {
      return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

insert code:

```
boolean insertData = db.insertUserData(UsernameInput, PasswordInput, Firstname, Secondname);

            if (insertData)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account successfully made", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account not successfully made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            startActivity(new Intent(Biometric_create_user.this,MainActivity.class));

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username : " + UsernameInput + "\nPassword:  " + PasswordInput + "\nFirst Name : " + Firstname + "\nSecond Name : " + Secondname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: please upload your table creation code

Comment: did you actually write this in the code -> ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues(); or did you just misspelled it here

Answer (score 0):

Your this line is misspelled:

```
db = new DatabseHelper(this);
```

Do check and verify it.
This problem could be due to this error.

Also, you are writing

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Are you sure that the method implements SQLiteOpenHelper ?

Try changing this line :-

```
ContentValues ContentValues = new ContentValues();
```

To :-

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues ();
```

Also, make the corresponding name changes in the next three lines.

Edit :- Declare your database outside the insertUserData method.
Ok so basically you write :-

```
db.insertUserData .......
```

Have you declared the DatabaseHelper db ?
Please share the full code of the file.

Also, you have this line :-

```
long result = db.insert("User",null, contentValues)
```

You have written the table name as User whereas the actual table name is USER.

Comment: Fixed these spelling mistakes, noticed an issue with my toast statement also. Yes i believe this is the correct method from what I have found online through online tutorials and webinars

Comment: I have updated my code to show full database code and insert code from the activity I am attempting to insert the data from

Comment: Now I am receiving this error message "    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.biosecurev1.DatabaseHelper.insertUserData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.biosecurev1.Biometric_create_user$1.onClick(Biometric_create_user.java:43)"

Answer (score 0):

The column names in your table are like `USERNAME` but the ones you're using in `ContentValues` are like `inputUsername`. The content values keys must match the table column names.

You can also use `insertOrThrow()` in place of `insert()` to get helpful exception messages, such as "no such column: inputUsername".

Comment: I thought ContentValues had to reference the variable you were going to insert not the column name?

Comment: The first arg to ContentValues put...() methods is the column name. Think of it as a map that maps column names to values.

Comment: Ah, so ContentValues("UsernameInput",username). maps the UsernameInput variable to the username column correct?

Comment: I am still receiving this issue. whether you know how to solve it or not. " java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.biosecurev1.DatabaseHelper.insertUserData(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at com.example.biosecurev1.Biometric_create_user$1.onClick(Biometric_create_user.java:43)"